# How can I tell ActiveRecord to discard an association cache AFTER a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

I'm trying to refresh an ActiveRecord has_many association also using a where clause. I'm finding two things that confuse me:

1. ActiveRecord does not use the cached association if there you call where on the association
2. Forcing ActiveRecord to query the db by passing true to the association method will fetch all the associations before the where clause is considered, causing an inefficient and unnecessary load of many objects into memory.

Is (1) expected behavior? [UPDATE -- see Frederick Cheung's answer below; each call generates a new relation so I believe the answer to this is yes]  I can't find this in the docs, so I feel iffy relying on my observation. If it is, then (2) is moot since AR will query the db each time anyway without telling it to force reload. But since I don't know, I have the follow-up question in case (1) is not guaranteed: How can I force reload without immediate query execution?

To illustrate (outputs are suppressed because they are not relevant, only the AR log output is shown):

`MediaFile` `has_many :assets`

Caching and forcing refresh works as expected:

```
m = MediaFile.delivered.offset(20).last
### log suppressed
1.9.3-p448 :078 > m.assets.map(&:id); nil
  MediaAsset Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `media_assets`.* FROM `media_assets` WHERE (`media_assets`.media_file_id = 533849)
1.9.3-p448 :079 > m.assets.map(&:id); nil
1.9.3-p448 :080 > m.assets(true).map(&:id); nil
  MediaAsset Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `media_assets`.* FROM `media_assets` WHERE (`media_assets`.media_file_id = 533849)
```

`where` clauses force a db fetch:

```
1.9.3-p448 :081 > m.assets.where(type: "Source").map(&:id); nil
  MediaAsset Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `media_assets`.* FROM `media_assets` WHERE (`media_assets`.media_file_id = 533849) AND (`media_assets`.`type` = 'Source')
1.9.3-p448 :082 > m.assets.where(type: "Source").map(&:id); nil
  MediaAsset Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `media_assets`.* FROM `media_assets` WHERE (`media_assets`.media_file_id = 533849) AND (`media_assets`.`type` = 'Source')
```

Passing true to the association method forces immediate loading:

```
1.9.3-p448 :083 > m.assets(true).where(type: "Source").map(&:id); nil
  MediaAsset Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `media_assets`.* FROM `media_assets` WHERE (`media_assets`.media_file_id = 533849)
  MediaAsset Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `media_assets`.* FROM `media_assets` WHERE (`media_assets`.media_file_id = 533849) AND (`media_assets`.`type` = 'Source')
```

Note that the first query in this last example executed first without the where clause. This seems suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off it's not true to say that the `where` clause forces a refresh - for active record the two are just separate relations and one being loaded has no incidence on the other. If you hold onto that relation it will only be loaded once, for example

```
rel = m.assets.where(type: 'Source'); nil
rel.map(&:id)
rel.map(&:id)
```

only hits the database once.

You can clear an association cache by calling reset on it:

```
m.assets.reset
```

(however since this returns the association, in the console this will trigger a reload unless you append `;false` or similar)

Comment: Thanks, I think i get it a little better now. So the where method (obviously) can't fetch cached data because it doesn't know that the arguments are identical, so it has to create a new relation. Is it safe to say then that calling #where on a possibly cached association will always trigger a db reload? (Though for the sake of absolute clarity I might prefer to explicitly call reset anyway.)

Comment: @andrew I don't believe where will ever affect the state of the association